# HTML Chrome Favicon Not Displaying

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, favicon

Hey guys I need some help on favicons for my site
I am using chrome and am writing the code in HTML and CSS
I am using the below line of code in my head tag

```
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" />
```

can I plz get some help on this fast

Comment: is "favicon-16x16.png" in the same directory as the html file?

Comment: you need to put the image at the same folder as the html file

Comment: @crimson589    Yea its in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?  Favicon.ico is an icon file that is displayed next to the URL in the browser bar. (See the StackExchange icon next to the URL).

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
```

or

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon-16x16.png" type="image/png"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon-16x16.png" type="image/png"/>
```